# MVC Remote validation attribute list parameter name binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have model that contains list of inner models with some parameters that I want to validate.

```
public class WrapperViewModel{
   public List<InnerViewModel> Inner {get; set;}
}

public class InnerViewModel{ 
   [Remote("Controller","ValidateName")]
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

So MVC create id for those multiple Inner objects like Wrapper_Inner_0__Name (...etc),

And when jquery.validator calling ValidateName()-Method it send parameter as
Query String Parameters:

```
Wrapper.Inner[0].Name: user_input_string
```

My Controller looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult ValidateName(string name)
{
   return JsonNet(Helper.IsValid(name));
}
```

I tried use Bind-attribute with prefix:

```
Bind(Prefix = "Wrapper.Inner[0]")
```

but it didn't worked and also I was unable to find how to use wildcard instead or 0,1,2 ...etc.

So is it possible to allow MVC auto-generate property name and have some kind of wild card parameter name in remote method, that will handle any names that auto-generated for list.

Comment: I've never had to do anything different for nested viewmodels, just decorate them as normal

Comment: But jquery validator send request to remote method with field id and because it is property of the one object in list it is something like "wrapper.inner[0].propertyname". So in the method I unable to handle other possible properties like "wrapper.inner[1].properyname" etc. Currently found work around, I have method with no parameter and get parameter directly from querystring variable by finding first key which contains for example "properyname". But it fills like there should be some more easy and clear way to do remote validation for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Access the request directly. Using .NET 6 but should be similar if version is less than .NET 6.

```
[HttpsPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Endpoint()
{    
   var filed = Request.Form[Request.Form.Keys.First()][0];
   //validation logic
}
```

Works with additional fields also just make sure to validate request in NETWORK for form properties order.
Works withing Razor Page but make sure to add your Request Verification token.